# EF Core + enum parameter in where query

Tags: c#, enums, entity-framework-core

I'm struggling to add an enum to a `where` condition I have on my queries.

I have the following definition for my class:

```cs
public enum Status
{
  Pending,
  Confirmed
}

public class Deposit
{
  public Status Status { get; set; }
}
```

Whenever I add a `where` condition with a raw enum value, like in the below example, it works perfectly:

```cs
query.Where(d => d.Status == Status.Completed);

// Generated query:
Executed DbCommand (40ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT d.*
FROM deposit AS d
WHERE d.status = 'Completed'
```

Whenever I try to add this enum value as a parameter, it fails in the following query:

```cs
query.Where(d => d.Status == input.Status);

// Generated query:

Failed executing DbCommand (244ms) [Parameters=[@__searchInput_Status_Value_0='Completed' (Nullable = false)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
SELECT d.*
FROM deposit AS d
WHERE d.status = @__searchInput_Status_Value_0
```

If I try to convert this enum in my model creation, I keep having the same error, either with `string` or `int` conversion:

For string conversions:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Deposit>()
  .Property(d => d.Status)
  .HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<Status>());

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: enum_deposit_status = text
```

For int conversions:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Deposit>()
  .Property(d => d.Status)
  .HasConversion<int>();

Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: enum_deposit_status = integer
```

Can somebody give some light on it?
Thank y'all!! :)

Comment: "it fails in the following query". What error do you see in this case?

Comment: What is `enum_deposit_status`? If it is [PostgreSQL enum type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html), then it requires special [mapping in Npgsql provider](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html?tabs=tabid-1). While with `string` or `int` conversion you have to change the database column type.

Comment: @Sasha the error I see is this one I've shown above: "Operator does not exist: enum_deposit_status = <integer> or <text>". There is also a hint: "No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts."

Comment: @IvanStoev the mapping didn't help. The error still persists. Whenever add a value as a raw comparison, it works. The parameter comparison is not working, it seems

Comment: @Kiwanax What happens if you do `query.Where(d => d.Status == (int)input.Status);` ?

Comment: @Sasha same story, unfortunately :(

Comment: @Kiwanax, added an answer with a workaround. Another potential workaround is to use Npgsql-specific [HasPostgresEnum](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/enum.html) mapper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like this is an issue in the PostgreSQL EF Core provider.

The following workaround should solve it, but there are version limitations; See notes below.

Map:

```cs
modelBuilder.Entity<Deposit>()
  .Property(d => d.Status)
  .HasConversion(new EnumToStringConverter<Status>());
```

Code:

```cs
var statusFilter = new[] { input.Status };
query.Where(d => statusFilter.Contains(d.Status));
```

---

Notes regarding affected versions

The workaround above works for `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` versions 3.0, 5.0 (and hopefully 6.0, did not check it)

Versions 3 and 5 translate the code differently:

- 3.0 (with EF 3.x)

  ```
  info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
        Executed DbCommand (7ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
        SELECT d.*
        FROM deposit AS d
        WHERE d.status IN ('Completed')
  ```
- 5.0 (with EF 5.x)

  ```
  info: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20101]
        Executed DbCommand (15ms) [Parameters=[@__statusFilter_0='?' (DbType = Object)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
        SELECT d.*
        FROM deposit AS d
        WHERE b.status = ANY (@__statusFilter_0)
  ```

It won't work in 3.1; it fails with pretty much the [same error](https://github.com/npgsql/efcore.pg/issues/1190):

- 3.1 (with EF 3.x)

  ```
  fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
        Failed executing DbCommand (18ms) [Parameters=[@__statusFilter_0='?' (DbType = Object)], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
        SELECT d.*
        FROM deposit AS d
        WHERE b.status = ANY (@__statusFilter_0)
  fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
        An exception occurred while iterating over the results of a query for <...>.
        Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42883: operator does not exist: character varying = integer
  ```

Comment: version 3.0.0 worked with your workaround! Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

In case someone (myself included) runs into problems in the future when working with filtering a Postgres array of enums mapped as strings in EF Core, I'm just gonna make it clear that the workaround above works for arrays too, namely:

This does not work

```
query.Where(d => d.SupportedDepositTypes.Contains(DepositType.RecurringDeposit));
```

But this works

```
var filterValue = DepositType.RecurringDeposit;
query.Where(d => d.SupportedDepositTypes.Contains(filterValue));
```